# OpenGL draws in 16 colors after changing RGBA color

Tags: c++, opengl

When I try to draw a 2D circle in OpenGL with and RGBA color, it draws it with the nearest 16-color-palette color. Here's the code that I use.

```
// Init canvas
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0,Screen.Width(),Screen.Height(),0,0,1);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT,GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE);
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);

// Background
glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

[...]

glColor3f(Color.R,Color.G,Color.B);

glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
  glVertex2f(Pos.X - SX,Pos.Y - SY);
    for (int angle=0; angle <= 360; angle+=1)
      glVertex2f(Pos.X - SX + sin(angle*M_PI/180.0) * Size, Pos.Y - SY +  cos(angle*M_PI/180.0) * Size);
glEnd();

[...]

// Render
glFlush();
glDisable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
```

Color is a struct of type `Color`:

```
struct Color
{
  float R;
  float G;
  float B;
  float A;

  void operator =(Color Clr);
  bool operator ==(Color Clr);
};
```

The following code is used to setup the engine:

```
// Create context
GDC = GetDC(Handle);

// Create pixel format descriptor
PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR GPFD = {
    sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR),
    1,
    PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER,
    PFD_TYPE_RGBA,
    24,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,
    32,
    0,
    0,
    PFD_MAIN_PLANE,
    0,
    0,0,0
};
GPixelFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(GDC,&GPFD);
SetPixelFormat(GDC,GPixelFormat,&GPFD);

// Create resource
GRC = wglCreateContext(GDC);
wglMakeCurrent(GDC,GRC);

// Setup resource
glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glFlush();
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

When I debug this code and reading the Pixel Format with `DescribePixelFormat()`, the debugger outputs the following: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12669217/Debugger.jpg
Also, the flags `PFD_GENERIC_FORMAT` and `PFD_NEED_PALETTE` are not set.

This is the desired output (before I used OpenGL): https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12669217/CR_Desired.png

This is the actual output (text and background aren't implemented yet): https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12669217/CR_Actual.png

Comment: Anything change if you set `c[Red|Green|Blue|Alpha][Bits|Shift]` to zero?

Comment: If you use `PFD_TYPE_RGBA`, this notion of color palettes is meaningless. You would need an "indexed" color mode for paletted rendering to occur.

Comment: @genpfault No, still the same.

Comment: @Andon I don't want to use a palette, I want to use RGBA, but OpenGL draws like a 16-color-palette was used.

Answer (score 3):

In WGL, the pixel format descriptor `PFD_TYPE_RGBA` will get you a pixel format that uses *bitplanes*. There are no color palettes when using RGBA, however, this mode is subject to the number of bits you allocate per-plane and any shifting.

I would suggest using:

```
PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR GPFD = {
    sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR),
    1,
    PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER,
    PFD_TYPE_RGBA,
    24,
    0,0,0,0,0,0, // No Shift Bits or Arbitrary Bitplane Allocation
    0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,
    32,
    0,
    0,
    PFD_MAIN_PLANE,
    0,
    0,0,0
};
```

I suspect the shift bits fields are responsible for your unusual behavior. If you set too many of these values unusually you will be given a pixel format that is not hardware accelerated. For instance, 32-bit z-buffer is not supported on a lot of hardware (24-bit Z + 8-bit stencil is much more compatible).

What you should *REALLY* do is call `DescribePixelFormat (...)` after selecting your pixel format, and seeing what WGL actually gave you. WGL searches for a pixel format that most closely matches the format you request.

Take a look at the reference for [ChoosePixelFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318284%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), on MSDN. It states the following:

> **Remarks**
>
> > You must ensure that the pixel format matched by the ChoosePixelFormat function satisfies your requirements. For example, if you request a pixel format with a 24-bit RGB color buffer but the device context offers only 8-bit RGB color buffers, the function returns a pixel format with an 8-bit RGB color buffer.

UPDATE:

Add this code to your setup, and examine the data structure of `GPFD` in a debugger:

```
DescribePixelFormat (GPixelFormat, &GPFD);
```

Pay special attention to the fields like `cColorBits` and `cDepthBits`.

There are a couple of flags you should check too, but a debugger is not going to make this easy. In your code you should test:

- `GPFD.dwFlags & PFD_GENERIC_FORMAT`
- `GPFD.dwFlags & PFD_NEED_PALETTE`

Comment: When I use your Pixel Format, the drawing has the same result. And I don't know which index I have to use in DescribePixelFormat.

Comment: @Genecyll: You would use the return value from `ChoosePixelFormat (...)`. It might be helpful if you included the full code you are using to setup your render context in your question, or at least the code that selects the pixel format.

Comment: Here's the output from the debugger: [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12669217/Debugger.jpg). Both flags are turned off.

Comment: @Genecyll: It is interesting that your cAuxBufers is non-zero, but other than that everything looks correct. Can you include the image with the debugger output in your question text along with an image showing the "16-color" effect? Also, have you enabled `GL_COLOR_MATERIAL`?

Comment: I now enabled `GL_COLOR_MATERIAL`, still with the same result.